# How does constant throughput timer in Jmeter works?

Tags: jmeter

how does the delay between requests is computed. I have simple Jmeter script with following 4 components :

1. thread group - number of threads set to 10, reset other fields have default values.
2. Http Sampler - named as Thread - ${__threadNum} Req -${__counter(TRUE)} 
   hitting URL- google.co.in
3. Constant throughput Timer : Target throughput- 60, Calculate Throughput on -All Active threads.
4. View result in table listener.

Summarized test results are below  :
[image: Results]

**Please explain how the delay between the requests and number of requests to be created are computed . Please Explain other field values of " Calculate Throughput on ".**

Also If i have ultimate Thread group instead of thread group, Have hold for load set to some value, so in that case how the number of requests to be sent during hold load time period are calculated?

Answer (score 4):

Constant Throughput Timer **pauses** active threads to reach throughput level you define.

Remember 2 things:

- Throughput Timer isn't able to create threads, it can only slow them down so make sure that you provide enough threads to reach desired target throughput
- Throughput Timer is quite accurate on "minute" level, you need to "wait" for it to start working as expected for 60 seconds.

See [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for more details.

In some cases for some people it's more convenient to use [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which comes with [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/), you can configure target throughput providing multiple steps and seeing the impact on a graph.

[image: Throughput Shaping Timer]

Comment: how is to calculate the pause the timer will introduce ?

Comment: how do we calculate the pause the timer will introduce between 2 requests ? also if we use Ultimate thread group , and hold load for set to some value, thread/users would be hitting the server continuously, so what would be the gap between consecutive hits. I have read the article earlier as well, but still could get my doubts clear regarding  "Calculate Throughput on" field. Please explain it with some illustration. Thanks :)

Comment: In my current script i have used CTT as 60, How do we compute the time in this scenario?

Comment: How the CTT value, thread count and response time can be related, is there any formula to find the pause value?

Comment: @DmitriT - just to confirm, the CTT is a means to slow down the test requests so that the server is not flooded with huge number of requests?So specifying throughput allows us to set the test requests to restrict within a certain bound - given by the CTT req/minute value. Right?

Comment: Quite right. Also there are [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) which are capable of kicking off extra threads to reach/maintain the desired throughput in case of current number of virtual users cannot produce the required load.

Answer (score 1):

From [JMeter Cookbook by Bayo Erinle](http://www.amazon.in/JMeter-Cookbook-Bayo-Erinle/dp/1783988282), The goal of the Constant Throughput Timer component is to get your test plan samples as
close as possible to a specified desired throughput. It achieves this by introducing variable
pauses to the test plan in such a manner that will keep numbers as close as possible to
the desired throughput. That said, throughput will be lowered if the server resources of the
system under test can't handle the load. Also, other elements (for example, other timers,
the number of specified threads, and so on) within the test plan can affect attaining the
desired throughput.

Comment: I m trying to understand the algorithm which works behind the constant throughput Sample. Lets say Response time is X, Constant throughput Timer is set to Y, In that case how much would be the pause between the requests

Comment: @nehabedi I've asked that exact question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677811/do-jmeter-timers-start-after-request-if-not-where-is-that-in-the-documentation