# Do JMeter Timers Start After Request Returns? If not, where is that in the documentation?

Tags: jmeter

The [JMeter docs in *3.4 Timers*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers) do not define the start and end of each timer:

> If you choose to add more than one timer to a Thread Group, JMeter takes the sum of the timers and pauses for that amount of time before executing the samplers to which the timers apply.

In this description, **it is not clear whether a timer starts at the moment a sampler request is fired or whether a timer starts at the moment a sampler request returns with the response.**

The [Apache JMeter docs for Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) defines a Constant Timer to be:

> If you want to have each thread pause for the same amount of time between requests, use this timer.

This too **leaves ambiguity about what "between requests" means - is is between the starts of requests, or between the end of one request and the start of the next one?**

When reading [a medium article *Performance Testing with a Think Time*](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9), the author Malith Jayasinghe defines *think time* to be:

> ... “think time” plays an important role when doing performance tests. It is defined as the time between the completion of one request and the start of the next request.

This is refreshingly specific as to the definition of think time, but I can't find any substantiation that this is how JMeter works in the docs.

**Where are authoritative docs on whether think time / wait time starts from the moment a request is fired or whether it starts from the moment a request returns?**

Answer (score 2):

As documentation about [JMeter Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers) says:

> A timer will cause JMeter to delay a certain amount of time **before** each sampler which is in its scope.

So, if you add any timer to sampler - JMeter will wait **before** start this sampler.
If you add timer in the same [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) with group of samplers - JMeter will wait specified time before each sampler.

Also, note:

> By default, a JMeter thread executes samplers in sequence without pausing.

Comment: Thank you for the quotes - I think you're on to something here; by default, a thread executes samplers without pausing, and adding a timer just adds a bit of time before each sampler without thinking about request time. That seems like a really obscure way to point out important information, so I'll wait a few days to see if someone points out a more precise & yet definitive answer in the jMeter docs.

Answer (score 2):

To answer it officially, you should look at JMeter's [Execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> 0 Configuration elements
>
> 1 Pre-Processors
>
> 2 Timers
>
> 3 Sampler  ...

Notice Timers are execute/delaying before handling current Sampler

Meaning the timer's delay is **before** sampler started

You can also glance at a sample JMeter code to see the delay happens is before handling sample

> ```
> delay(pack.getTimers());
>     SampleResult result = null;
>     if (running) {
>         Sampler sampler = pack.getSampler();
>         result = doSampling(threadContext, sampler);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set timer or wait thread after the response, then add **BeanShell PostProcessor** and add `Thread.sleep(5000);`

This will wait the next thread for 5 seconds after  getting the response of the current one.